Flutter Query request String encode in retrofit
I use dio + retrofit to make http requests.
I need to pass query param to request.
query param "KURZEMES PROSPEKTS" looks like "KURZEMES+PROSPEKTS" now. But i need this string to look like "KURZEMES%20PROSPEKTS" how i can do it ?
this is my code now.
 @GET('v2/address')
  Future<AddressHouses> getAddressesHouses(
    @Query('street_name', encoded: true) String? streetName,
  );


you can use the Uri.encodeQueryComponent function from the dart:core library to manually encode the query parameter.
@GET('v2/address')
Future<AddressHouses> getAddressesHouses(
  @Query('street_name') String? streetName,
) {
  
  streetName = Uri.encodeQueryComponent(streetName?? '');
  //...
}

Note that, you should remove the encoded: true parameter from the @Query annotation, as it's not necessary when you're manually encoding the query parameter.
